# g++ in cygwin doesn't create .exe file

Tags: g++, cygwin

I just installed cygwin on a new Windows box running Windows 7 and I am getting funny behavior when I compile a c++ program.  Here's what I type:

```
g++ test.gpp -o test
```

On my other Windows boxes, this creates an exe file, test.exe, and it is, of course an executable.  But on this installation, the file test is created.  To my surprise, it is not an executable, but rather looks like a debug file (in ascii printables).  If I instead type:

```
g++ test.gpp -o test.exe
```

Then I do get the executable test.exe.  (1) why in all my other implementations do I get the executable, but not with this most recent attempt?  (2) Why do I care?  Well, I also work on linux boxes and am not accustomed to typing the extension ".exe".  (I *hate* that aspect of non-linux files!)  I am guessing that there is some sort of one-time flag I can set to make the default file that g++ creates be a .exe file.

The problem with this problem is that none of you may be able to reproduce it!  (I can't on my other machines!)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two different `g++` versions installed on the problem system? Maybe a MinGW install as well? Try `which g++` to check.

Comment: @WarrenYoung: Or `type -a g++` to see all version in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, `g++` doesn't recognize the `.gpp` extension.  Rename the file from `test.gpp` to `test.cpp` and try again.

On my Cygwin system, `g++ test.gpp` gives me an error message:

```
... file format not recognized; treating as linker script ...
```

Cygwin compilers do create executable files with a `.exe` extension (because Windows requires it), but it also lets you refer to such files without the suffix.  So, for example:

```
ls -l test.exe
```

and

```
ls -l test
```

should both show you the same file.  (If you happen to have files with both names, things can get a bit confusing -- so don't do that.)  `g++`'s `-s` option also treats the `.exe` suffix specially, so `-o test` and `-o test.exe` should do the same thing.

I don't know why you're seeing the behavior you describe.  Perhaps you happen to have something in `test.gpp` that looks like a valid linker script?

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ test.gpp -o test
```

This should create a file called test (with no extension). If that file is created than give executable permission the file using `chmod +x test`

than use `./test` to run it. see if it works.

Comment: No, on Cygwin the created file is `test.exe` (which can also be referred to as just `test`) -- and `g++` should create it with execute permissions.